# Angular Call array by index in loop

Tags: angular

I've error in this code when click `CheckAllOptions`  to select all checkbox

He select also checkbox in another property

I need only property I clicked it in loop

```html
     <div  class="section-property" *ngFor="let item of properties; let i = index; " >
            <div class="icon-view"  >
                <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> 
            </div>
            <div class="icon-view" style="left: 10px;">
                <input type="checkbox" name=""  >
            </div>
            <img src="../../../assets/images/breakfast.png" style="height:150px;border-radius: 10px;" routerLink="/property/{{item.id}}"   />
            <div layout="row" class="bottom-section" fxLayout="row" >
                <div class="col-6"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu"></i></div>
                <div class="col-6 title-property" routerLink="/property/{{item.id}}"><span>{{item.title}}</span></div>             
            </div> 
            <mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu" class="submenu">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <div mat-menu-item (click)="$event.stopPropagation();" (click)="CheckAllOptions(i)">
             <input (input)="type=$event.target.value" type="checkbox"  value="0" > send All
                    </div>
  
                    <div mat-menu-item *ngFor="let checkbox of checkboxes; let index = index; " (click)="$event.stopPropagation();">
                        <input [(ngModel)]="checkbox.checked" name="checkbox.checked[index]" (input)="type=$event.target.value" type="checkbox"  value="{{checkbox.value}}" >
                        {{checkbox.name}}
                    </div>
                    <div mat-menu-item>
                        <button class="sendData" (click)="SendData(item.id)">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </mat-menu>
        </div>
```

in .ts file

```typescript
    CheckAllOptions(i) {  
    console.log(i);
    let selectedCategory = this.checkboxes
    if (selectedCategory.every(val => val.checked == true))
      selectedCategory.forEach(val => { val.checked = false });
    else
      selectedCategory.forEach(val => { val.checked = true }); }
```

Array checkbox

```typescript
    checkboxes: any[] = [
    { name: 'send location', value: '1', checked: false },
    { name: 'send images', value: '2', checked: false },]
```

Comment: can you explain what you need to do bit more and add a stackblitz demo

Comment: In the .ts script, you are telling the program: "If all the property are checked => uncheck all, else check all.". Is that what you expect ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-q4e5ej?file=src/app/app.component.html   Demo

Comment: when select all i need select only one property not all